# Fetch all binded events using jquery

Tags: jquery, events

I have a component in a vast codebase. Before I bind any events or do anything I want to fetch all the currently bound events for that components.

Does jquery provide a way to fetch all the currently bound events for a component?

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery stores the bound events in the special data functions of jQuery.

Try this out:

```
var events = $('div').data('events');
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot. Does that mean that "all the events" of all the components can be fetched that way.

Someone mentioned that while attaching events if I give a namespace they can be fetched, but I am not sure what that means.

Comment: This should contain every event bound on the element, might not contain live events but every normal event, namespaced or not, should be in there.