# List all jquery event binded on an dom element

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a spaghetti coded website. Some strange action apears on certain elements.
There is nothing listed on the Chrome event listener.

Is there any other way to look at that ?
Like writing in the console something like that:

```
$('#myElement').getEvents(); //Not a real code
```

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [Fetch all binded events using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979462/fetch-all-binded-events-using-jquery)

Comment: You can try inspecting the ancestor chain to see if any of the `#myElement` ancestors have bound event listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another option, you can get between the jQuery binding and the element using the following hook:

```
(function($){
    var event_add_orig = $.event.add;
    $.event.add = function(){
        console.log('Added event (' + arguments[0].tagName + '::' + arguments[1] + ')');
        // arguments[0] // elem
        // arguments[1] // types
        // arguments[2] // handler
        // arguments[3] // data
        // arguments[4] // selector
        event_add_orig.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

That way you'll see every binding being applied throughout the page. You can then use more logic to distill it down to a specified event or element. Keep in mind that this would need to be defined before anything else on the page executes, but of course after jQuery's defined.

Comment: Great solution, arguments[2] give me enought info to find the problem. Thx